# Linear independent subset of a set of vectors [GAP]

Tags: linear-algebra, gap

I'm trying to find a linearly independent subset of a set of vectors in a vector space over the rationals. Looking up "independent", "linear independence", or anything of the sort hasn't helped, since I only found the [`LinearIndependentColumns(mat)`](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap25.html#X843A976787600F13) function, which isn't what I needed. I looked around in the tutorials, but there is nothing of the sort. Is there a ready function that does this, or do I have to do it myself?

If it's the latter, how can I do it? Is there a way to "choose" the first vector, take the next, and look for non-trivial solutions and add it to my list, if there exist no solutions? Is there a more efficient way to find the subset?

Comment: Do you also have a requirement that every vector from the set should be a linear combination of vectors from this linearly independent subset?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov No. I'm just trying to write down a list of linearly independent vectors $L \in S$, where $S$ is the original set of vectors.

Comment: I think you can indeed start with one vector, then take next, and use `Dimension(VectorSpace(Rationals, ... ));` to see if the dimension increases. If yes, add the new vector, if not - discard it and go to the next vector. If you don't need to find a maximal linearly independent set, then stop when you need.

Comment: Thanks, that's a clever way to go about it! I do indeed need a maximal linearly independent set.

Comment: You may be also interested in `??Basis` then.

Comment: P.S. Also, the dimension of the whole thing is the upper limit, so if you found as many vectors, you do not have to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Take the rationals as a vector space over the rationals. Is the set $\{ 1 \} \subset \mathbb{Q}$ linearly independent? Similarly, take $\mathbb{Q}^2$ as a vector space over the rationals. Is the set $\{ (1, 0), (0, 1) \}$ independent? What about the set $\{(1, 0) \} \subset \mathbb{Q}^2$?

Given a vector space $V$ over a field $k$, a set $S \subset V$ is said to be *linearly independent* provided that if you have a sum of the form
$$
\sum_{s \in S}a_s\cdot s = 0
$$
with each $a_s \in k$ and all but finitely many zero, then you must have that $a_s = 0$ for all $s \in S$.

You should be able to see from the definition above that *any* subset of a nonzero-vector space of cardinality 1 is independent.

This ends up being equivalent to saying that given a set $S \subset V$, we have that $S$ is independent if you can't write any vector in $S$ as a linear combination of the other vectors in $S$.

Does that help clarify things?

Comment: Not sure whether you misunderstood my question, or I your answer. I know what linear independence is and how it's calculated. I'm just trying to program it using gap

Comment: Ah. I think I misunderstood your question. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Let's use these ten vectors to construct an example:

```
gap> v:=[ [ 1/2, 2, 1/2, -1/2, 0 ], [ 0, 1, -1, -1, 1/2 ], 
>   [ 0, -2/3, 1/3, -1/2, -3 ], [ 0, 2, 1/5, 1/2, 0 ], 
>   [ 1/2, 2, 1/2, -1/2, 0 ], [ 1/2, 0, -1, 0, 0 ], 
>   [ 1, 0, 2, 0, 1/2 ], [ 0, -2/3, 1/3, -1/2, -3 ], 
>   [ 1/2, 3/5, -1, 0, 1/5 ], [ 0, -2/3, 1/3, -1/2, -3 ] ];;
```

Now if you need a basis which does not necessarily consist of elements of the given set of vectors, you can use `Basis`:

```
gap> V:=VectorSpace(Rationals,v);
<vector space over Rationals, with 10 generators>
gap> Dimension(V);
5
gap> bas:=Basis(V);
SemiEchelonBasis( <vector space of dimension 5 over Rationals>, 
[ [ 1, 4, 1, -1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, -1, -1, 1/2 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 7/2, 8 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 93/26 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ] )
gap> AsList(bas);
[ [ 1, 4, 1, -1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, -1, -1, 1/2 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 7/2, 8 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 93/26 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ]
```

If you need to find elements *from* the given set, I suggest to enumerate elements of `v` and add them to the resulting list in case the dimension of the subspace that they generate together increases. The dimension of the vector space gives the upper bound, so the process may be stopped when it is reached:

```
gap> lis:=[];
[  ]
gap> for r in v do
>   V1:=VectorSpace( Rationals, Concatenation(lis,[r]) );
>   if Dimension(V1) > Length(lis) then
>     Add(lis,r);
>     if Length(lis)=Dimension(V) then
>       break;
>     fi;
>   fi;
> od;
gap> lis;
[ [ 1/2, 2, 1/2, -1/2, 0 ], [ 0, 1, -1, -1, 1/2 ], 
  [ 0, -2/3, 1/3, -1/2, -3 ], [ 0, 2, 1/5, 1/2, 0 ], 
  [ 1/2, 0, -1, 0, 0 ] ]
```

Comment: The Dimension function gives me the following error:

Comment: Can not see the error in the comment. Maybe post it as an update to the question?

Comment: I found out why I got the error. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Maybe revert the edit and post that as a new question? Otherwise my answer does not answer your current question at all :)

Comment: Discovered https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3050734/ - will have a look. Perhaps you can now accept this answer again, as it matches the question ;-)